# Spring Boot:: Not able to override context path from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

I am just trying to set my context path as /v1/audit-management instead of my application war name(Audit_Management_DS-1.0-SNAPSHOT) but it's not working. My entry in application.yml (location of this is src/main/resources) is as follows

server:
    context-path: /v1/audit-management

When I hit the URL http://localhost:1234/v1/audit-management its giving HTTP 404. However http://localhost:1234/Audit_Management_DS-1.0-SNAPSHOT is working fine.

Comment: I thing i forget to mention that i am deploying my application on external Tomcat 8, not the embeded Tomacat of spring boot.

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy your application as a war file to an external servlet container Spring Boot's server isn't being used so configuring its context path has no effect. If you want to configure the context path you'll need to rename your war file or use one of the other mechanisms supported by Tomcat such as using a context.xml file in your war.